# What is ./.local/share/Trash (Unix)

Tags: ubuntu, xfce

I'm using a virtual machine to run a Java web app. The OS is XFCE (Ubuntu) and I found the files that I want with the command `find -name "something"`. These files are in ./.local/share/Trash/... So, I would like to know what is this repository? (Because the "trash" is freaking me out!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably don't want to store things in that trash folder. It's where deleted files go when a sudo user has deleted them as root.

See, for example, https://askubuntu.com/questions/246888/why-does-local-share-trash-still-use-lots-of-space-even-after-emptying-the-tr

Comment: // , In OSX, I think the convention is to use `.Trash` for the trash folder owned by the user.