# Why does Emacs attempt to use ~/.local/share in OSX even when not run as root?

Tags: macos, emacs, elisp, spacemacs

For programmatically managing deletion when a program does not have root access, it makes sense to move "deleted" files to a location local to the user directory.

Normally, Emacs does this using the function `make-directory-internal()`.

However, my Emacs does this on a location not owned by its user, *without* testing for ownership, first:

```
make-directory-internal("~/.local/share/Trash")
```

According to https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Testing-Accessibility.html, I can test for ownership pretty easily before attempting a write to a directory:

```
(file-accessible-directory-p "/foo")
     ⇒ nil
```

This Emacs code, instead, tries to use folders that are in my ~, but owned by root. It does not handle the exception by using a folder that it actually has access to.

For example, it's using `~/.local/share/Trash`, instead of `~/.Trash`.

Is there some reason better exception handling hasn't gotten into the code? Do I need to submit a patch, or is this a normal, accepted way to program?

In short, **why** does this code do this?

According to @Erlaunis' question, [What is ./.local/share/Trash (Unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349369/what-is-local-share-trash-unix)?, my `emacs` cannot edit `~/.local/share/Trash` because it's owned by root.

Because of this, I end up running into B.S. like the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Creating directory" "Permission denied" "/Users/myusername/.local/share/Trash")
```

I posted the full error output here: http://0bin.net/paste/YSQgBhxbFwBnaJer#vcTHnyC+BE-SepxK+5rLmNt73GUg9dZr1Kk6CekiqnQ [link available until 2016 04 23)

(NOTE: While I think part of this question has some general interest outside of Emacs Lisp, I would not say no to suggestions to transfer it to emacs.stackexchange.com. Please advise in comments.)

Comment: // , It seems like a fairly common (https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/1cec8q/packageel_cant_install_creating_directory/) problem, with an obvious solution (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Testing-Accessibility.html). I wonder what I'm missing, here.

Comment: Here is a related thread entitled **Delete files to Trash on OS X**:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15009/delete-files-to-trash-on-os-x/15012

Comment: // , // , That's definitely related. Doesn't say _why_ it's done this way, in *module management*, no less, in the first place, though.

Comment: Why is ~/.local/share/Trash owned by root on your system?  Sounds like a misconfiguration to me.

Comment: // , @Stefan I thought so too, at first, but I did some reading. I own `~/.Trash`, and `root` owns `~/.local/share/Trash`. It's not a misconfiguration according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349369/what-is-local-share-trash-unix. I guess it keeps things organized when `root` trashes things from my home directory?

Comment: @NathanBasanese: I see no reason why we should believe this "Reacher Gilt" guy on this matter.  The link he provides as supporting evidence is completely unrelated.  It seems this askubuntu question is just one of the many cases of "the blind leading the blind".  It's **very odd** to have root owned files anywhere under `~/`, so if `.local/share/Trash` was an exception, we'd know about it.

Comment: // , Well, I, at least, live in the blind category, here, then. My `$ stat .local` gives me a response of `drwxr-xr-x 4 root staff`. I have compiled myself Emacs 25 and I use http://brew.sh. Would you care to go in and comment on that "Reacher Gilt" guy's answer, then?

Comment: // , My `$ ls -laF | grep local/` gives me a response of `drwxr-xr-x    4 root      staff         136 Feb 10 11:25 .local/`.